# How to use polymer to format an input as the user of types

Tags: polymer

As the user types I want to have thousand separators format the number. How would I accomplish this with a polymer component? I have the logic to change a string into, separated thousands I just want to know the polymer approach to do this .

I achieved something similar with angular by using ngmodel.$parse function on their controller and directives

Answer (score -1):

Use a tag with data-binding.

```
<input type="text" value="{{someVar}}" />
```

if you have `someVar` defined in your Script as `@observable` you should be able to use your logic on it to add the Separator.